# How to join two regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have this two regex

```
/^[^+\x2f\s\x5c ]+$/ - don't accept slashes, + or white spaces

/(?!^\d+$)^.+$/ - Don't be only numbers
```

I would like to join them in one. How can I join them?

Comment: Isn't it evident? `^(?!\d+$)[^+\x2f\s\x5c]+$`. Or a clumsier, but "easy" way: `(?!^\d+$)^[^+\x2f\s\x5c]+$/`

Comment: What do you want to get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join them as:

```
^(?!^\d+$)[^+\x2f\s\x5c ]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI0rU7/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?!^\d+$)[^+\x2f\s\x5c ]+$/
```

Negative look-ahead followed by the matching.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go for something like this over regex because it's more readable:

```
if (
    !ctype_digit($string) &&
    strpos($string, '\\') === FALSE &&
    strpos($string, '/') === FALSE &&
    strpos($string, '+') === FALSE &&
    !preg_match('white spaces regex goes here', $string)
) {
    // Good to go
}
else {
    // Error
}
```